# How to get the HTML of a website and parse it with NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse the XML from a website (e.g. "http://www.kick-girl.com/?cat=3")

I can easily get the XML using:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.kick-girl.com/?cat=3"];
 NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]);
```

However when I try to use NSXMLParser it simply does not work.  I have already tried converting the string to data

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSData *d = [s dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding];
NSXMLParser *xmlparser = [NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:d];
xmlparser.delegate = self;
[xmlparser parse];
```

And it still does not work.  The NSXMLParserDelegate methods do not get called.
e.g.

```
- (void)parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
```

I have also tried using AFnetworking to see if that would help

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOp = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

requestOp.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
[requestOp.responseSerializer setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/xml", @"text/xml", @"text/html", nil]];
[requestOp setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSXMLParser *xmlparser = responseObject;

    xmlparser.delegate = self; 
    [xmlparser parse]; //Delegate methods are not called for some reason...
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"OOPS: %@", error);
}];
[requestOp start];
```

I don't understand what is the problem.

I get a parse error from -parser:parserErrorOccurred:

```
Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=65 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 65.)" UserInfo=0x8da6ce0 {NSXMLParserErrorLineNumber=2, NSXMLParserErrorColumn=17, NSXMLParserErrorMessage=attributes construct error
```

}

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the XML that I got from the webpage is not perfect and has some weird stuff in it.  Although a web browser is quite forgiving when it comes to reading xml, the nsxmlparser is very strict.

To prevent that weird stuff from coming out I simply took a substring of the parts that I wanted, then removed whitespaces like new lines carriage returns and tabs.  And did some string manipulations to make sure the tags were actually balanced.